# Show filename, date, size in shell

Tags: linux, shell, ls

I have a newbie question regarding linux command `ls`.
How can I only show the filename(without the full path), the size of the file and the date?
for example I want to show somehting like this:

```
somehting.jpg 4096 04/05/2015
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `find` command:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -printf '%f %n %CY-%Cm-%Cd\n'
```

to get in the format you want. You can adjust the directory path to whatever path you want to use.

Comment: my directory path is stored in a variable. also i want to return files ending in .jpg inside that directory. how can i modify this command to do that? I'm not familiar with the syntax that's why I'm asking.

Comment: As in: `find ${dir_name}/*.jpg -maxdepth 1 -printf '%f %n %CY-%Cm-%Cd\n'` where dir_name is the variable with directory name.

Comment: this seems to work but I want to return also the size of every file and the date of the file. Now it only returns the .jpg. Sorry for constant questions.

Comment: No. It would return size & date too.

Comment: yea you are right. Sorry. In my terminal it returns size and date but when I run it in Yii with `shell_exec` it only returns the .jpg and I don't understand why. I run it like this: `$view=shell_exec('find '.$path.'/*.jpg -maxdepth 1 -printf "%f %n %CY-%Cm-%Cd\n"');`

Comment: I got it to work finally! it works perfect, I just adder `%s` to get the file size. thank you very much for the help!

Answer (score 0):

thr, you can try using the following command:

```
ls -shgGA | awk '{print $7"\t"$5"\t"$1}'
```

This will list the contents of the directory you are in / specify. If I am understanding your question correctly. You should see output like this:

```
agentRename.sh  2012-03-06  4.0K
.aptitude/  2010-05-04  4.0K
backup/ 2013-10-22  4.0K
.bash_history   2015-05-06  64K
.bashrc 2013-10-04  4.0K
```

Comment: it seems to work fine in my terminal but im trying to use that with shell_exec and maybe im having trouble with the syntax. I do something like that: `shell_exec('ls -shgGA '.trim($mountusb).'/*.jpg | awk "{print $7"\t"$5"\t"$1}"` and I get NULL

Comment: It's [not safe parse ls output](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). On different platforms, output may vary depending on what `ls` is there.